# Magento, show a popup "thank you" message at subscribe newsletter

Tags: php, magento, newsletter, subscribe

I want to show a popup with something like "Thank you for subscribe" instead of the green notification.

**Notification Image:**

[image]

So, I don't know how to get the message in session, or override the SubscribeController to send some parameter by get to know that the user has subscribed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to override the `SubscriberController.php` controller of `Newsletter` module. The controller has `newAction()` which is used for adding the subscriber's details.

Create your new module and in `config.xml`  of your module -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
   <frontend>
    <routers>
        <newsletter>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <knewsletter before="Mage_Newsletter">MyNamespace_MyModlulename</knewsletter>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </newsletter>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
```

Then add `SubscriberController.php` in your controller folder -

```
<?php
 require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', "Mage_Newsletter").DS."SubscriberController.php";
 class MyNamespace_MyModlulename_SubscriberController extends Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController{

  public function newAction() {
       // can copy the content of original newAction and modify accordingly.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do above.

If you open the main template files from your theme i.e 1column, 2column-left etc you will notice code like :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
```

First you need to comment these, this will remove the message showing currently on the pages.

Now go to footer.phtml of you site and add something like :

```
<?php if($this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessageCollection()->count()): ?>
    <div id="global_messages_popup" style="display: none">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="global_messages_close" style="display: none" title="<?php echo $this->__('Hide messages') ?>">&times;</a>
        <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>
    </div>
<?php $this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessageCollection()->clear(); ?>
<script>
// Here you can write js code to open above div in a popup or something else.
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Above is not tested so please check it yourselves.